# sqlalchemy insert data from dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

How can I insert data with a python dict?

This doesn't work:

```
class Date(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dates'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'www'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    salutation = Column(VARCHAR(1))
    lastname = Column(VARCHAR(128))
    firstname = Column(VARCHAR(50))
    zipcode = Column(VARCHAR(255))
```

...

```
statement = dict({
    'salutation': form.get('salutation'),
    'lastname': form.get('lastname'),
    'firstname': form.get('firstname'),
    'zipcode': form.get('zipcode')
})
new_entry = Date(**statement)

session.add(new_entry)
session.commit()
```

**This produces this error output**

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'
>   [SQL: 'INSERT INTO ....

Comment: Take a look what values are returned by each `form.get(...)`. Are they compatible with the datatypes of your `Date` class?

Comment: Thank you, "salutation" was the problem - make a string and it worked...